# Same relation is created two times between two nodes in neo4j in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I have two types of Nodes "Post" and "Comment" and I am using ActiveNode of ruby to create nodes and relations. The following are my Post and Comment Models:

```
class Comment 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :body, type: String

  has_one :out, :post, type: :comments_on
end

class Post 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :title, type: String
  property :body, type: String

  has_many :in, :comments, origin: :post 
end
```

When I create a comment on a particular Post then relation is created but it is created two times. I am unable to find why it is created two times.

Here I am sharing code to create comment class

```
def create
     @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @comment.save
            format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you used to create the comment?  Also, you're welcome to join us in our chat room if that is better for you: https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j

Comment: I shared the code for create comment,please help me.

Comment: Could you output `comment_params.inspect` and share that as well?

Comment: Could you explain more please.I am not getting.

Comment: The code doesn't tell me too much. The `comment_params` variable which is being passed into `Comment.new` probably has the details which would be relevant.  Could you put a `puts comment_params.inspect` at the beginning of the `create` method and then copy/paste the output into your question?

Comment: Its give error.undefined local variable or method `comment_params' for #<PostsController:0x007f1c7287c680>

Comment: Ummm, not sure what to say.... ;)  If the code is from the Rails' generated scaffolding like I suspect then `comment_params` would be a method defined further down.  Perhaps you could dig in and figure out what's going on to see what it's returning.  It also might be helpful to see the `log/development.log` resulting from the request to see the params as parsed by Rails

Answer (score 0):

Somebody else asked this question and I was just able to track it down to a bug that cropped up in version 6.0.2 of the gem.  I think I've got the bug fixed now.  Try the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'neo4j', github: 'neo4jrb/neo4j', branch: '6.1.x'
```

If that works for you I can release a gem with the fix